# Crone job using hangfire with asp.net core Webapi project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created an ASP.NET Core WebApi project using Clean Architecture.
Now, I want to create a Crone job project seperately using Hangfire
which will send emails using some logics which will be written in in Webapi project.
Can anyone suggest me the best solution for this

Comment: MyProject.Core (1 project for your logic or more if you want)
MyProject..WebApi (apis)
MyProject.Hangfire (for ur jobs)

Answer (score 0):

To use Hangfire create a Cron job, you could check the [Hangfire document](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html) to install and register the Hangfile. And then search "Hangfire Schedule Background Jobs in ASP.Net Core" using Google or Bing, there should have multiple articles. Such as:

[Background Tasks Made Easy With Hangfire And .Net 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/background-tasks-made-easy-with-hangfire-and-net-5/)

[Background Processing In ASP.NET Core With Hangfire](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/background-processing-in-asp-net-core-with-hangfire/).

[Schedule Background Jobs Using Hangfire In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/schedule-background-jobs-using-hangfire-in-asp-net-core/)

To send emails in asp.net core application, you could try to use [the SmtpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0).